# PyDrive download image python

Tags: python, email, google-drive-api, imaplib, pydrive

I have mail messages which contain attachments.
I need to upload the attachments from mail to google drive.
For mail I'm using [imaplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html) and for google drive I'm using [pyDrive](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/quickstart.html)

I'm using the below code to get attachment:

```
if mail.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':

        for part in mail.walk():
            if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
                continue

            if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:

            attachment = part.get_payload(decode=True)
```

I have `payload` my attachment in mail. Now I can't understand how upload `payload` to google drive using pyDrive. I've tried this, but it did not work

```
attachment = part.get_payload(decode=True)
gd_file = self.gd_box.g_drive.CreateFile({'title': 'Hello.jpg',
                                                          "parents": [{"kind": "drive#fileLink", "id": folder['id']}]})
                gd_file.GetContentFile(attachment)
                gd_file.Upload()
```

**UPD:**

This code is work, but i think its bad solution(we save image localy, then upload this image in google drive)

```
attachment = part.get_payload(decode=True)
                att_path = os.path.join("", part.get_filename())
                if not os.path.isfile(att_path):
                     fp = open(att_path, 'wb')
                     fp.write(attachment)
                     fp.close()

                gd_file = self.gd_box.g_drive.CreateFile({'title': part.get_filename(),
                                                          "parents": [{"kind": "drive#fileLink", "id": folder['id']}]})
                gd_file.SetContentFile(part.get_filename())
                gd_file.Upload()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`GetContentFile()`](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/pydrive.html#pydrive.files.GoogleDriveFile.GetContentFile) is used to save a [`GoogleDriveFile`](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/pydrive.html#pydrive.files.GoogleDriveFile) to a local file. You want the opposite so try using [`SetContentString()`](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/pydrive.html#pydrive.files.GoogleDriveFile.SetContentString) instead, then call `Upload()`:

```
gd_file.SetContentString(attachment)
gd_file.Upload()
```

**Update**

`SetContentString()` won't work if you are dealing with binary data, such as that contained in an image file. As a work-around you can write the data to a temporary file, upload to your drive, then delete the temporary file:

```
import os
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

tmp_name = None
with NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as tf:
    tf.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
    tmp_name = tf.name    # save the file name
if tmp_name is not None:
    gd_file.SetContentFile(tf_name)
    gd_file.Upload()
    os.remove(tmp_name)
```

Comment: thnks for your answer, i try using `SetContentString` i have error `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'`

Comment: OK, `SetContentString()` does not support bytes objects, i.e. binary strings. It expects a `str` object which is then encoded as UTF8. This will not work because you are dealing with binary data. You can save the attachment to a temporary file first, then use `SetContentFile()` instead. See updated answer.

Comment: No worries. Just one more thing to mention if security is an issue. There is a possible race condition after the file has been written and closed where an attacker could replace the file content with other data. If that's a concern then you need to look at a more secure way to do it.